# what is replacement of sem_getvalue() in MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, semaphore

I have a code that use unnamed semaphore with thread join. I wanted to compile it in MacOS but I figured out unnamed semaphore is not supported in MacOS and dispatch semaphore is a replacement for it.
In my code there is a point that I want to post semaphore till semaphore counter become equal zero so I use sem_getvalue() function. Here is my code

```
sem_getvalue(&(event), &res);
while (res <= 0) {
   sem_post(&(tcp_client->resp_event));
   res++;
}
```

1.Is there any way to handle this with dispatch semaphore?

2.Is there any better way to replace unnamed semaphore in MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very suspect thing to want to do with a semaphore. It suggests that you should be using some other synchronization mechanism, perhaps a condition lock.

That said, no, dispatch semaphores don't directly provide a mechanism like this. But a semaphore is a very basic synchronization primitive on which almost any other synchronization scheme can be built. In order for us to suggest something, though, we'd need to know what you're using it for. For example, under what circumstances are you "resetting" your semaphore like this and why?

Comment: I have some client server service that request and responses handle in different threads. The thread which handles requests wait for thread which handles responses. There is stop point in program that make all threads to exit after some cleanup. Between these processes it might be a wait without post. I want to check if this happened I call sem_post() to let response thread terminate.